# detect hardware virtualization via command line

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualization

IS there a command line tool to detect hardware virtualization like this : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ee2a17f-8538-4619-8d1c-05d27e11adb2&displaylang=en

Comment: Any particular OS?

Comment: windows xp and 7

Comment: updated tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page describes how:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592

It looks like you run it with the /q switch and then check the ErrorLevel:

```
C:\HAVTool\sources\i386\havtool.exe /q 
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```